# Why derivative of analytic polynomial equals ${\partial \over \partial x}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I solved the following exercise:

Find the derivative $P'(z)$ of

$$ P(x,y) = x^3 - 3xy^2 - x + i(3x^2 y - y^3 -y)$$

and

$$ P(x,y) = 2xy + i(y^2 -x^2)$$

Show that in each case $P'(z) = P_x$. Explain.

The only part I didn't manage was the "explain" part. For an analytic polynomial we have $P_y = i P_x$. And Since the derivative from any direction has to be equal I figured that we'd have to have

$$ P'(z) = i P_x$$

Instead, we have $P'(z) = P_x$.

> What am I missing? Why is $P'(z) = P_x$ and not $P'(z) = iP_x$ as I
>   expected?

Answer (score 1):

This is taken, I guess, from the book by Bak and Newman. In the corresponding chapter the authors show that a polynomial $P=P(x,y)$ is analytic is and only if $P(x,y)=P(x+iy,0)$ identically. If you give an increment to $z=x+iy$, you will just vary the *first* argument of $P(x,y)$. Hence it is really *reasonable* that $P'(z)=P_x$.

Comment: That is true and I understand your explanation. But I'm still confused why we don't have $P'(z) = P_x(z) = P_y(z)$. Don't we have
$$ P_x (z) = \lim_{h\to 0, h\in \mathbb R} {f(z+h) - f(z) \over h} = \lim_{h\to 0} {f(z+h) - f(z) \over h} = P'(z)?$$

Comment: @student Try to do the same computation for $P_y$ as you did above for $P_x$ and you will see that you'll get a "$i$" in front: $P_y = iP'(z)$. Instead of working with the defintion of the derivative it's perhaps easier to try to differentiate $P(z) = P(x+iy)$ using the chain-rule. We have $\frac{\partial P(z)}{\partial x} = \frac{dP(z)}{dz} \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dP(z)}{dz}$ since $\frac{d(x+iy)}{dx} = 1$. Similary we have $\frac{\partial P(z)}{\partial y} = \frac{dP(z)}{dz} \frac{dz}{dy} = i\frac{dP(z)}{dz}$ since $\frac{d(x+iy)}{dy} = i$.